# Equivalent strpos() function in the Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

Please tell me what is the equivalent of following command in Blade

```
if (strpos($a,'are') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Comment: what's the problem with this?

Comment: I'm using Blade template engine and don't want to use php code.

Comment: @if(strpos($a,'are') !== false)
// do stuff
@endif

Comment: Thank you dear friend . This is the right answer

Comment: Ok. I'm adding this to my answer. Hope you may accept my answer. :)

Comment: Read the documentation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the existence of a substring within a string then str_contains() is what you're looking for [Laravel Helper Methods](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-str-contains)

If you want to use with blade then.

```
@if(strpos($a,'are') !== false) 
    // do stuff 
@endif
```